# Ссылка на всю область

Tags: html, css

Не силен в верстке. С помощью флекс сделал панель, на ней располагается меню. Просто делать текст ссылками надоело, хочется, чтобы при наведении мыши на всю область (текст и весь его прямоугольник) менялся цвет, ну, и можно было нажать мышку и перейти. Как это проще всего сделать, какие теги посмотреть?

Comment: посмотреть на `:hover` в css

Comment: a:hover {
 color: #CC0000;
 text-decoration: underline;
} вот так делал, а как на всю область это распространить?

Comment: применить не к `a` а к тегу-области

Comment: <div class="a">text</div> В css файле применяю к классу а, вроде как работает, но не как ссылка. Что еще нужно сделать, чтобы курсор в руку превращался?)))

Comment: нужно почитать какой-нибудь справочник по css, а не каждый чих тут спрашивать.

Comment: конечно, вы правы, спорить бессмысленно, но можно было просто проигнорировать меня и заниматься своими делами, как и другие))

Answer (score 0):

```css
 /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

[Источник w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp).